# How to make all cells boldface in LaTeX table?

Tags: latex, miktex

Given the following LaTeX table, how can I make all cells have a bold style?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]%
        \centering
        \caption[Data description]{Dataset description}
        \begin{tabular}{|l|l|c|c|c|c|}
            \hline
             &Dataset      &Samples&Numerical&Categorical&Class\\ \hline
            1&Horse        & 300   &  7      & 16        & 2   \\ \hline
            2&Ionosphere   & 351   & 32      &  1        & 2   \\ \hline
            3&Band         & 540   & 13      &  6        & 2   \\ \hline
            4&Australian+MV& 621   &  3      & 11        & 2   \\ \hline
            5&Hepatitis    & 155   &  2      & 17        & 2   \\ \hline
            6&Credit       & 690   &  3      & 12        & 2   \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
        \label{tab:data}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can set the formatting of **each column** in the tabular argument with `>{...}`, see [Tabular, make a column or a row emphasized](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12467/tabular-make-a-column-or-a-row-emphasized):

```
\begin{tabular}{|>{\bfseries}l|>{\bfseries}l|>{\bfseries}c|>{\bfseries}c|>{\bfseries}c|>{\bfseries}c|}
```

Use the `*{num}{str}` syntax to make it shorter and more readable:

```
\begin{tabular}{*{2}{|>{\bfseries}l} *{4}{|>{\bfseries}c} |}\hline
```

I.e. 'two times flush left and bold', then 'four times centred and bold'. (Note that [\bf is deprecated](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41681/correct-way-to-bold-italicize-text).)

Your MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array} % otherwise you get "Error: Illegal character in array arg."

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]%
        \centering
        \caption[Data description]{Dataset description}
        \begin{tabular}{*{2}{|>{\bfseries}l} *{4}{|>{\bfseries}c} |}\hline
             &Dataset      &Samples&Numerical&Categorical&Class\\ \hline
            1&Horse        & 300   &  7      & 16        & 2   \\ \hline
            2&Ionosphere   & 351   & 32      &  1        & 2   \\ \hline
            3&Band         & 540   & 13      &  6        & 2   \\ \hline
            4&Australian+MV& 621   &  3      & 11        & 2   \\ \hline
            5&Hepatitis    & 155   &  2      & 17        & 2   \\ \hline
            6&Credit       & 690   &  3      & 12        & 2   \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
        \label{tab:data}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

---

You can also set the formatting of a **whole row** (less interesting in this case) - see for instance [How to change a whole row of a table](http://www.tex.ac.uk/FAQ-wholerow.html).

---

Note: you can [make a single cell normal again](http://www.forkosh.com/pstex/latexcommands.htm) by using `\normalfont{}`.

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]%
% If you want all in bold face then enclose it between {\ bf  }
    \centering {\bf
    \caption[Data description]{Dataset description}
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|c|c|c|c|}\hline            
       & Dataset      & Samples & Numerical & Categorical & Class\\\hline
        1 & Horse        & 300   &  7      & 16        & 2   \\\hline
        2 & Ionosphere   & 351   & 32      &  1        & 2   \\\hline
        3 & Band         & 540   & 13      &  6        & 2   \\\hline
        4 & Australian+MV& 621   &  3      & 11        & 2   \\\hline
        5 & Hepatitis    & 155   &  2      & 17        & 2   \\\hline
        6 & Credit       & 690   &  3      & 12        & 2   \\\hline
    \end{tabular}
    \label{tab:data}
```